# Scrolling to bottom of div at every refresh

Tags: html, scroll, refresh

Currently, I have a div which refreshes every 8 sec. This div basically loads a php page.
However, I am facing a problem of scrolling to the bottom of this page. 
This is the code for the refresh and the scrolling to the bottom of the div:

```
 <script>
    var refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {            
         $('#responsecontainer').fadeOut("slow").load('forum.php').fadeIn("slow");

         $('#chat').attr({ scrollTop: $('#chat').attr("scrollHeight") });
    }, 8000);

    </script>
```

The div container code is as follows:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 300px; overflow: scroll; border: 5px ; background-color:#ccc ;" id="responsecontainer" name="chat">

            Loading..

 </div>
```

Please advice on how i can go about going to the bottom of the div when it is refreshed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The script should be called when the document is loaded. Then using the fadeOut and fadeIn animation will happen after load so it resets the scroll position. The script below will work but eventually without those animations.

The load method is a XHR call and it returns the response status, using which we can control  the data which is displayed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {            
    $('#responsecontainer').load('forum.php', function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
            $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
        else{
            $('#responsecontainer').scrollTop($('#responsecontainer').height());        
        }
    });
}, 8000);
});
```